# powershell to un-install muliple applications ?

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0, uninstallation, wmi-query

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm looking for a way to un-install multiple applications. I have a list of applications in a text file that i want to Un-install.  Here's the code i have so far:

```
# Retrieve names of all softwares to un-install and places in variable $app

$App = Get-Content "C:\temp\un-installApps.txt"

# Cycle through each of the softwares to un-install and store in the WMI variable

Foreach ($AppName in $App)
{
    $AppTmp = Get-WmiObject -query "Select * from win32_product WHERE Name like" + $AppName 
    $AppNames = $AppNames + $AppTmp
}

foreach ($Application in $AppNames )
{
    msiexec /uninstall $Application.IdentifyingNumber
}
```

The following lines causes the issues

```
$AppTmp = Get-WmiObject -query "Select * from win32_product WHERE Name like" + $AppName 
$AppNames = $AppNames + $AppTmp"
```

Any ideas how i can get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because there is no space between `like` and the application name, and there needs to be single quotes around the application name. That part should look like `like '" + $AppName + "'"`.

However, you could do the whole script more simply like this:

```
$App = Get-Content "C:\temp\un-installApps.txt"

gwmi win32_product|
    where { $App -contains $_.Name }|
    foreach { $_.Uninstall() } | out-null
```

Comment: Void caused me issue, so i used this:

$App = Get-Content "C:\temp\un-installApp.txt"
gwmi win32_product| where { $App -contains $_.Name }| foreach { $_.Uninstall() }

Comment: Try it with @manojlds edit. `[void]` would have worked if I wrapped the pipeline in parentheses.

Comment: Is there a "do not reboot" generic command line flag?  Or is that program specific?  (script is working, but it rebooted my machine when I wasn't expecting it!)

Comment: @granadaCoder There is no option for the `Uninstall()` method. You could change the `foreach` to use `msiexec`. It would look something like `foreach { msiexec.exe  /norestart /q/x $_.IdentifyingNumber REMOVE=ALL }' See: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/691bd01e-249c-47f1-861e-3eaeba3d875e/win7-powershell-uninstall-application-and-restart-request