# Removing multiple apps using powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, wmi

I want to create a script to remove a bunch of apps. I want to do this without user interaction once I've started the script.

This is the script I have so far; it doesn't work but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do:

```
$App = Get-Content "C:\ListOFApps.txt" #get a list of apps
$args= '/quiet /norestart' # stores arguments for start-process 

#gwmi gets the list of applications 
# where selects just the apps im interested in removing 
# start-process removes each app using msiexec with quiet and norestart options 

gwmi win32_product | where { $App -contains $_.Name } | foreach {Start-Process 'msicexec /uninstall ' $_.IdentifyingNumber -ArgumentList $args -wait}'
```

This is the error that occurred:

```
ForEach-Object : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Process.
At C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\406f96a1-19b4-4e0d-af1b-b1ac2e32a6ba.ps1:3 char:62
+ gwmi win32_product| where { $App -contains $_.Name }| foreach <<<<  
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
 $_.IdentifyingNumber
Start-Process 'msicexec /uninstall $_.IdentifyingNumber' -ArgumentList $args -wait
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Errormessage? Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Didn't you post the same question before? Edit that question and wait for answers.

Comment: I have posted a similar question before.  However, after running the previous script, i redefined the question to un-install quietly.  I'm new to stack overflow so i apologize if ive done the incorrect action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [powershell to un-install muliple applications ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938646/powershell-to-un-install-muliple-applications)

Answer (score 1):

You have an unbalanced single quote on the end of the line with the "foreach." I suspect fixing that is only the start of your problems. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Also you have the Process misspelled.  Should be "msiexec" not "msicexec"